# compiling zurb framework-cli install with gulp

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, gulp

Instructions on [Foundation website](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) for using gulp to compile a framework-cli install are

```
gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass({
    includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
```

I have implemented using

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

But, after executing

```
> grunt sass
```

I get the error from sass:

```
> TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
```

Comment: Instead of gulp, consider using the native ember-cli build process and use ember-cli-foundation-sass

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using gulp to compile your Sass, but you are running the command `grunt sass`. You should run the command `gulp sass` instead. Grunt and gulp are two different/separate task runners.